# Merging two csv files with a common column but uneven lengths

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have two csv files:
csv file 1 contains the following:

```
California,C1,G1,K1,Dine-In,B,25
California,C2,G2,K1,Dine-In,A,8
Hawaii,H1,J1,L1,Dine-In,A,22
Hawaii,H2,J2,L2,Dine-In,A,20
```

csv file 2 contains:

```
Hawaii,10
California,20
```

I wanted my output to be:

```
California,C1,G1,K1,Dine-In,B,25,20
California,C2,G2,K1,Dine-In,A,8,20
Hawaii,H1,J1,L1,Dine-In,A,22,10
Hawaii,H2,J2,L2,Dine-In,A,20,10
```

I have done my code:

```
with open(r'file 1.csv', 'r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    dict2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}

with open(r'file 2.csv','r') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    dict1 = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)

result = OrderedDict()
for d in (dict1, dict2):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        result.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)

with open('combined data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in result.iteritems():
        w.writerow([key] + value)
```

but it gives me an output of:

```
California,C1,G1,K1,Dine-In,B,25
California,C2,G2,K1,Dine-In,A,8
Hawaii,H1,J1,L1,Dine-In,A,22
Hawaii,H2,J2,L2,Dine-In,A,20
Hawaii,10
California,20
```

got any ideas on this?

Comment: Reading `file 1.csv` like that to a dictionary will throw away rows with duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to load `file 2.csv` in as a dictionary, and then append this to each row when reading `file 1.csv` as follows:

```
import csv

with open(r'file 2.csv','rb') as f_file2:
    dict2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in csv.reader(f_file2)}

with open(r'file 1.csv', 'rb') as f_file1, open('combined data.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv.reader(f_file1):
        csv_output.writerow(row + dict2[row[0]])
```

Giving you:

```
California,C1,G1,K1,Dine-In,B,25,20
California,C2,G2,K1,Dine-In,A,8,20
Hawaii,H1,J1,L1,Dine-In,A,22,10
Hawaii,H2,J2,L2,Dine-In,A,20,10
```

Answer (score 2):

### A [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) solution

```
import pandas pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=None)
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=0)
res.to_csv('combined.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

`combined.csv`:

```
California,C1,G1,K1,Dine-In,B,25,20
California,C2,G2,K1,Dine-In,A,8,20
Hawaii,H1,J1,L1,Dine-In,A,22,10
Hawaii,H2,J2,L2,Dine-In,A,20,10
```

### In Steps

Read the first file into a data frame:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=None)
```

It looks like this:

```
            0   1   2   3        4  5   6
0  California  C1  G1  K1  Dine-In  B  25
1  California  C2  G2  K1  Dine-In  A   8
2      Hawaii  H1  J1  L1  Dine-In  A  22
3      Hawaii  H2  J2  L2  Dine-In  A  20
```

Do the same for the second file:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=None)
```

Results in:

```
            0   1
0      Hawaii  10
1  California  20
```

Merge at column `0`:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=0)
```

Now, `res` looks like this:

```
            0 1_x   2   3        4  5   6  1_y
0  California  C1  G1  K1  Dine-In  B  25   20
1  California  C2  G2  K1  Dine-In  A   8   20
2      Hawaii  H1  J1  L1  Dine-In  A  22   10
3      Hawaii  H2  J2  L2  Dine-In  A  20   10
```

Finally, write to a csv file without the header and the index:

```
res.to_csv('combined.csv', header=None, index=False)
```